# Calling function inside a JSON object

Tags: json

I'm trying to add a new property call fill to JSON by calling a function inside it. But I'm getting an error saying a function is not defined. I've called using `this` clause but still getting the same error.
here is my data.

```
 [{ key: 1, fill:this.fillcolor(mytext),text: mytext }]
```

`fillColor` function returns a color code when depending on the text name passed to it.

```
fillColor = (data) => {

         switch (data) {
           case 'NMP':
               return 'indigo400';
             break;
           case 'KPD':
               return 'pinkA200';
             break;
           case 'NMV':
               return 'orangeA400';
             break;
           case 'KRV':
               return 'lightBlue400';
             break;
           case 'NIP':
               return 'yellowA200';
             break;
           case 'KRU':
               return 'lightGreenA400';
             break;
           case 'UPS':
               return 'deepPurpleA100';
             break;
           case 'MK':
               return 'brown300';
             break;

           default:
            return 'pinkA200';

         }

   };
```

I still can't figure out why I keep getting this error. 
The parameter `myText` contains a name/property.

Comment: Try var fillcolor = function (data){ //your code}. Dont add this.fillcolor just fillcolor(data).@Tromesh

Comment: What is the "JSON object" your question title refers to? In what context are you defining `fillColor`? In what context are you calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the correct json structure like

```
[{"data":[["1","2"],["3","4"]],"aFunction":"function(){return \"foo bar\";}"}]
```

And the context you are referring is wrong. **this** in your code refferes something else.